# Custom Post Type content isn't shown

Tags: custom-post-types

My problem is to display the content of  custom post types. 
The Dashboard-preview shows the right content (/vita/vita-test/), but I can't see it at the homepage ( /vita/ ). It displays the content of index.php
Why isn't found „vita-test“?

My permalink is /%post_id%/%postname%/

my  post type $args

```
'rewrite' => array("slug" => "vita"),
'show_in_nav_menus' => true
```

I also use

```
query_posts('post_type=vita&post_status=publish');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Do you have an idea where my mistake is?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to register you post type with the `has_archive` argument to get an archive page at `/<post_type_slug>/`.

Eg.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'wpse70469_register');
function wpse70469_register()
{
    $args = array(
        'rewrite' => array("slug" => "vita"),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'has_archive' => true, // this makes the archive page work.
    );

    register_post_type('wpse70469_type', $args);
}
```

You might want read through the arguments for [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). You also don't need to include query posts like that.  WordPress will setup the correct post type and status based on the current request -- no need to do that manually.

Comment: in addition, it's probably worth mentioning that calling `query_posts` is neither required nor recommended

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response! I have register post type 'has archive' from the beginning - Any other idea where my mistake is?

Comment: Post more of your loop code.  `the_post` doesn't out put anything.  `the_content` will.